I'm trying to use VBA to create a hyperlink to a worksheet with the same name as the cell value
I'm writing a macro for use for inventory tracking. I want to have a table of raw goods that contains various details about each, including a ID, which is located in the first table column which happens to be column B in my case. In my macro, if a new raw good is needed, the user will input the details into the "RawGoods_Table", and the table column [Raw Goods ID] is where I want the hyperlink to be.
When the code starts, an input box asks the user for th new ID, and this is set as shtName as a string. Then I search for shtName in the RawGoods_Table, column Raw Goods ID to verify that the information is there. The location is set as cell with is a range. After ensuring that a worksheet doesn't already exist with shtName, a new one is created, and named shtName and formatted based on a Template worksheet. I then want to go back to the RawGoods_Table cell and create a hyperlink to the worksheet that was just created, while keeping the text to display the same as it was.
For reference, I'm using Excel version 16.16.25 (200810) on mac
I tried this code and get subscript out of range.
cell is found earlier in the code, and I've verified it by using a msg box.
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtName As String
Dim cell As Range

Worksheets(“03. Raw Goods”).select
cell.select

ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="’sht.shtname!A1’”, TextToDisplay:=cell.value"


If it helps any, the entire code is below. Everything else seems to work fine, except obvisouly since I've inserted the hyperlink portion, the code stops before the end, but without the hyperlink part everything does finish fine. I'm not a coder, so I'm sure it's not the best, but seems to be good enough for now.
Sub Add_New_Raw_Goods()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngLast As Range
Dim ShCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer



'USER ENTER NEW RAW GOODS ID
shtName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the sheet name", _
Title:="Search Sheet")

'VERIFY IF RAW GOODS ID IS IN RAW GOODS TABLE
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B")
Set cell = rng.Find(What:=shtName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Please New Enter Raw Good ID Information Into Raw Goods Table"
Exit Sub
Else
End If


'CHECK IF WORKSHEET ALREADY EXISTS
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If sht.Name = shtName Then
MsgBox shtName & " already exists."
Exit Sub
End If
Next sht


'ADD NEW RAW GOODS ID WORKSHEET
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

sht.Name = shtName


'CREATE BIN CARD FOR NEW RAW GOODS WORKSHEET
    Sheets("00. RG-0000").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(shtName).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B16").Select


'CREATE HYPERLINK TO BIN CARD FROM RAW GOODS TABLE RAW GOODS ID COLUMN
'Worksheets("03. Raw Goods").Select
'cell.Select

'selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="#'" & selectedCell.Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="" & selectedCell.Value & ""





Worksheets("03. Raw Godds").Select
cell.Select

ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="’sht.shtname!A1’”, TextToDisplay:=cell.value"




'UPDATE STOCK SUMMARY TABLE

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("02. Stock Summary")
        If .Range("B9").Value = "" Then
            Set rngLast = .Range("B9")
        Else
            Set rngLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        rngLast.Value = shtName
        
    End With


'ARRANGE WORKSHEETS ALPHABETICALLY

ShCount = Sheets.Count

For i = 1 To ShCount - 1
    For j = i + 1 To ShCount
        If UCase(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase(Sheets(i).Name) Then
            Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



You missed to tell us whitch statement exaclty throws that error, but my guess would be that you have a type in the sheet name of the statement Worksheets("03. Raw Goods").Select.

The line were you add the hyperlink looks wrong. The link points to a sheet named sht.shtname and not to a sheet name linke the value of this object. You have to merge the string like in the out comment line (selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add ...)

I understood that the user has to enter a string in a column of a table and run this code to enter the same string into the input box. That doesn't seem user friendly. Wouldn't it be better to run the code as soon as the value has been entered? Please clarify.
